# В void linux не работает "stack setup"

Tags: linux, haskell, x86, haskell-stack

При запуске `stack setup` выводится сообщение:

> Unable to find installation URLs for OS key: linux32-ncurses6

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить ncurses5-compat-libs
apt-get install ncurses5-compat-libs
это должно решить проблему